# Problem connection from PHP to Apache ActiveMQ using AMQP

Tags: php, activemq-classic, amqp, php-amqplib

I tried searching the web up and down - and either they point me towards RabbitMQ which is out of the question because the customer specifically asked for ActiveMQ / Amazon MQ which is basically ActiveMQ in the amazon cloud. Other results suggest using a different protocol (STOMP) - which I cant do because again the customer allows only the access via AMQP

So I'm at a loss .. can you help me get going ? I tried with [PHPamqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) but I get errors accessing the already running activeMQ broker "Invalid frame type 65 in ....AbstractConnection.php:571" during connection build up.

```
<?php
namespace Test;
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPSocketConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

class Test {
   private $host='192.168.3.66';
   private $port=5672;
   private $user='guest';
   private $password='guest';
   protected $connection;
   protected $channel;

public function __construct() {
   $this->connection=new AMQPSocketConnection($this->host, $this->port, $this->user,$this->password);
   $this->channel=$this->connection->channel();
}
...
```

The error occurs already here during execution of the constructor, when I build an instance of my Test class to send messages. Before you ask, I tried with different AMQP connection types offered by the library - the error is always the same. Honestly as it worked in C# using the amqpnetlite library I'm a bit at a loss what is missing and where this error stems from. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ultimately we settled on using c# to code it, building up on an example provided by a developer that maintains the broker we send to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the README.md](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/README.md) php-amqplib supports AMQP 0.9.1. However, [ActiveMQ supports AMQP 1.0](https://activemq.apache.org/amqp). Unfortunately the two protocols are not compatible. You'll need to find a PHP AMQP client which supports 1.0 if you want to communicate with ActiveMQ or Amazon MQ. According to [this thread](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/issues/583) there are no plans to support AMQP 1.0 in php-amqplib.

The [amqpnetlite client supports AMQP 1.0](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/blob/master/README.md) which is why it works with ActiveMQ.

Comment: Do you know of anything PHP related that aims for AMQP 1.0?

Comment: I searched for a bit, and I couldn't find one.